# How to manually load spark-redshift AVRO files into Redshift?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift, avro, spark-avro

I have a Spark job that failed at the `COPY` portion of the write.  I have all the output already processed in S3, but am having trouble figuring out how to manually load it.

```
COPY table
FROM 's3://bucket/a7da09eb-4220-4ebe-8794-e71bd53b11bd/part-'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=XXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXX'
format as AVRO 'auto'
```

In my folder there is a `_SUCCESS`, `_committedxxx` and `_startedxxx` file, and then 99 files all starting with the prefix `part-`.  When I run this I get an `stl_load_error` -> `Invalid AVRO file found. Unexpected end of AVRO file.`  If I take that prefix off, then I get:

```
[XX000] ERROR: Invalid AVRO file Detail: ----------------------------------------------- error: Invalid AVRO file code: 8001 context: Cannot init avro reader from s3 file Incorrect Avro container file magic number query: 10882709 location: avropath_request.cpp:432 process: query23_27 [pid=10653] -----------------------------------------------
```

Is this possible to do?  It would be nice to save the processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error from Redshift.

The COPY works after I deleted the _committedxxx and _startedxxx files (the _SUCCESS file is no problem).

If you have many directories in s3, you can use the aws cli to clean them of these files:

```
aws s3 rm s3://my_bucket/my/dir/ --include "_comm*" --exclude "*.avro" --exclude "*_SUCCESS" --recursive
```

Note that the cli seems to have a bug, --include "_comm*" did not work for me. So it attempted to delete *all* files. Using "--exclude *.avro" does the trick. Be careful and run the command with --dryrun first!!